# The implementation for `promise` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've read this article:

[Callbacks are imperative, promises are functional: Node’s biggest missed opportunity](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2013/03/30/callbacks-are-imperative-promises-are-functional-nodes-biggest-missed-opportunity/)

There's a code:

```
var p1 = new Promise();
p1.then(console.log);
p1.resolve(42);

var p2 = new Promise();
p2.resolve(2013);
p2.then(console.log);

// prints:
// 42
// 2013
```

This makes sense to me. Very declarative code.

However, once I really use `promise` in node.js
doing

`npm bluebird`

Here is the actuall code that does work:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var r1;
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve){
  r1 = resolve;
});

p1.then(console.log);
r1(42);

var r2;
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve){
  r2 = resolve;
});

r2(2013);
p2.then(console.log);
```

To me the former code looks more reasonable.
What is going on?

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just confusing implementation glitch.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

def = Promise.defer()
// {promise: <Promise>, resolve: <Function>, reject: <Function>}

def.promise.then(console.log)

def.resolve(123) // 『123』
```

works.

Comment: To be fair - `console.log` as a free function doesn't work in the browser and `Promise.defer()` is deprecated and is no longer supported since Bluebird `2.0`.

Comment: Could you show me the alternative then please?

Comment: Promise.resolve(123).then(console.log) - as the duplicate says.

Comment: ok, so mine does not work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually it doesn't make sense to create a pending promise or deferred at all.. just use `Promise.resolve`:

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve(42);
p1.then(console.log);

var p2 = Promise.resolve(2013);
p2.then(console.log);
```

Comment: I actually want to `resolve` in any time, even after `then` is called. But thanks.

Comment: @KenOKABE oh, in that case you just want to chain from the already returned promise. If something doesn't return a promise you can promisify it, going and resolving stuff yourself results in really ugly code